# Set div height to height of browser

Tags: html, css, height

I'm not an expert in making fancy websites, but for my new 'project' I want to have everything in the div "container page" automatically filled over the total heigth of the browser (or screen)? I tried this, but only the info within the first div "slide1" is placed over the total height of the browser. The div "menu" and the second div "slide1" is not forced on the height of the browser. Any suggestions?

```css
#container_page {
height:100vh !important; 
}

#slide1 {
    background: url('images/Frontpage.png');
    background-size: cover !important;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 15000;
    text-align: center;
}

.overlay-background {
    background: url('images/overlay-background.png') left top;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999 !important;
}

.menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    background: url('images/menu-background.png') left top;
    z-index: 9999;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.171);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.171);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.171);
    border-top: 3px solid rgb(139, 250, 2);
}
```

```html
<div id="container_page">
<div id="slide1" class="slide" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
 <div class="overlay-background home-padding" style="left: 0px; top: 0; bottom: 0px; min-height: 350px;">
  <div class="container clearfix">
   <div class="grid_12">
    <div class="home-text">
    </div>
    <br></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-shadow" >
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Slide 1 End -->
<!-- Menu Start -->
<div class="menu" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
 <div class="container clearfix">
  <!-- Logo Start -->
  <div id="logo" class="left">
   <a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/logo.png"></a> </div>
  <!-- Logo End -->
  <!-- Navigation Start -->
  <div id="nav" class="right">
   <ul class="navigation">
    <li data-slide="1">Home</li>
    <li data-slide="2"><span lang="en-gb">Products</span></li>
    <li data-slide="4"><span lang="en-gb">Technology</span></li>
    <li data-slide="6"><span lang="en-gb">Company</span></li>
    <li data-slide="10">Contact</li>
    <li class="clear"></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Navigation End --></div>
</div>
<!-- Menu End -->
<!-- Slide 1 Start -->
<div id="slide1" class="slide" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" style="background: url('images/slide-background.png'); z-index: 9900;">
 <div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="grid_12">
   <div id="core" class="wrapper">
    <div id="title_frontpage">
     <span lang="en-gb">Experts</span></div>
   </div>
   <!-- Button Bottom Start -->
   <div class="button-bottom">
    <a class="button" data-slide="2" title=""><span></span></a>
   </div>
   <div class="clear">
   </div>
   <!-- Button Bottom End --></div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `float: left` perhaps?

Comment: @RamenChef Which div?

Comment: [`100vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"

Comment: Not really a helpful answer. Could you please write bit more?

Comment: To which div do I have to add this?